# Excel 2003 template that saves the filename based on a cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I need to make an Excel 2003 template to be used a customer order entry  form, that when the user saves the file, it will automatically save with the filename with the value of cell B2  (customer ID) as the prefix and the current date as the suffix e.g. “2001XC_5-24-12”.  I don’t know VBA.
Thank you very much  in advance, Nathaniel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `BeforeSave` event handler to do this.

Put this code in the `ThisWorkbook` module

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs [B2] & "_" & Format(Date, "m-d-yy")
    Cancel = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Note:

- You need to account for which sheet you want cell `B2` from, so use something like:

  ```
  ThisWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet Name Here").Cells(2,2) ...
  ```
- When creating file names with dates, I reccomend you use formay `yyyymmdd` so they will sort chronologically